# Laplace transform converging to zero

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a sequence $X_n$ of random variables, whose Laplace transform $F_n(\lambda)=\mathbb{E}(e^{-\lambda X_n})$ satisfy for every $\lambda\geq0$
$$F_n(\lambda)\to1\qquad (n\to\infty).$$
Is it enough to conclude that $X_n\to0$, or in which sense would it converge ?

Comment: That can't happen: $F_n(0) = {\mathbb E}(1) = 1$ for all $n$.  Do you mean $F_n(\lambda) \to 1$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, it's now corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Lévy's continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Continuity) says roughly that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ iff the Characteristic function ([roughly related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Related_concepts) to the Fourier transform of the distribution) of $X_n$ converges pointwise to Characteristic function of $X$.

Note that

- 1 is the Laplace transform of the delta function at 0.
- It is easier to work with the Fourier transform.

Also, the formula you give is a [two-sided Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform) if $X_n$ are real-valued random variables. It is interesting look at the concept of [moment generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).

Answer (score 1):

Yes but only if $X_n$ is positive. [Lévy's continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem) is valid for positive random variables and the Laplace transform instead Fourier's (see Kallenberg's "Foundation of Modern Probability" Th. 5.3).